# JSF accessing backing map object

Tags: jsf, dictionary, param

I have a jsp subview page that I have passed a parameter to and I want to then pass that parameter to a map's get() method that is stored in a session bean.

Ex:

```
<h:panelGrid id="panelGrid1" rendered="#{MySessionBean[param.id].showPanelGrid1}">
...
</h:panelGrid>
```

In the above example MySessionBean implements the Map interface and I have my own custom get method that will create an object and put it in the map if none exists for the key [params.id]. When I run the code in debug mode my get method for MySessionBean never gets called and my panel is always rendered. Am I not passing parameters correctly? Or accessing the parameter passed to the subview correclty?

Here is how I passed the parameter to this subview:

```
<f:subview id="subview1">
  <jsp:include page="/MyTemplatePage.jsp">
    <jsp:param name="id" value="staticUniqueId1"/>
  </jsp:include>
</f:subview>
```

The reason I'm trying to do this is so I can include this template subview multiple times in a single page so that each instance won't have the same backing bean objects. Thus using a map in the session and passing it an id to gain access to the backing beans for each instance.

Also, I am limited JSF 1.2, JSTL 1.1, JBoss 4.0.4. So I can't use answers that use RichFaces or JSF 2.

**EDIT: 11/22/11 11:23**

I Replaced the [param.id] with a static string value.

```
<h:panelGrid id="panelGrid1" rendered="#{MySessionBean.MY_TEMP_VAL.showPanelGrid1}">
  ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

And everything worked. It triggered my map get method and accessed the session beans and everything. So it is clearly not liking the whole using [params.id] passing to the map object. Not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 2):

In JSF2 the proper and easy solution would be to use composite components. Since you are stuck with JSF 1.2 and jsp you could use [tag files](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html) instead. These are like regular jsps but with the extension `tag` or `tagx` and placed under `WEB-INF/tags`. I'm using the xml syntax in the example below, in a file name `example.tagx`:

```
<jsp:root version="2.1"
          xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
          xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <jsp:directive.attribute name="myBean"
                             required="true"
                             rtexprvalue="false"
                             deferredValue="true"
                             deferredValueType="com.example.MyBean"/>
    <h:panelGrid id="panelGrid1" rendered="#{myBean.showPanelGrid1}">
    ...
    </h:panelGrid>
</jsp:root>
```

In a jspx you then have to declare the namespace like `xmlns:myTags="urn:jsptagdir:/WEB-INF/tags/"`, in a jsp the syntax would be:

```
<%@taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="myTags" %>
```

The custom tag can then be used multiple times on a page and the right backing bean can be passed as an attribute like this:

```
<myTags:example myBean="#{myBeanInstance1}" />
```

**Edit:** You might also need a file `WEB-INF/tags/implicit.tld` to specify the version:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<taglib xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
        version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
        <tlib-version>2.1</tlib-version>
</taglib>
```

Comment: I'm geeting an exception of "org.apache.jasper.JasperException: jsp.error.beans.property.conversion". I think it doesn't like EL in the tag attribute myBean="#{myBeanInstance1}". I've tried to find other examples on custom JSF tags and all of them want to assign a backing bean to the tag when they describe it in the tld file. But I just want to use a jspx file to describe the contents.